# How to change a ng-view depending on a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm building a site using Angular, that displays images from a folder **images**. The images are titled **image1, image2, etc.**. The site displays the images in a view, one image at a time.

The page displays the first image at first. To see the next image, the user clicks **next**. To see the previous image the user clicks **Previous**. To see the first image, the user clicks **First**.

So far the I can only make the site display the first image, but I can't figure out how to get the next images.

**My Index.html(the main page):**

```
    <script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="../modules/myModule.js"></script>
    <script src="../Controllers/myController.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/MyScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#next">Next</a></li>
        <li><a href="#first">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="#previous">Previous</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="images" class="ng-view">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**My partial view called myView:**

```
<div>
    <img src="../images/image1.jpg" />
</div>
```

**My Controller, called myController:**

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {

});
```

**My Module, called myModule:**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
```

**My script, called myScript:**

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "image1.html"
    })
    .when("/next", {
        templateUrl: "image1.html"
    })
    .when("/first", {
        templateUrl: "image1.html"
    })
    .when("/previous", {
        templateUrl: "image1.html"
    });
});
```

I need to change when next and when previous to the current image minus or plus one. **first try:**

```
var page = 0;

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "image1.html"
    })
    .when("/next", {
        page++;
        templateUrl: "image" + page + ".html"            
    })
    .when("/first", {
        templateUrl: "image1.html"
    })
    .when("/previous", {
        page--;
        templateUrl: "image" + page + ".html"
    });
```

but got a squiggly red error line under the variable `page` inside app.config

**Second try:** putting a variable in myController;

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.page = 0;
});
```

but I still got the squiggly line in app.config.

How can I do this?

*Please forget the entire algorithm of what to do when arriving at the last image or the first image. I'll take care of that myself. Pretend like my logic in my first try makes sense.*

Answer (score 2):

Why use routing for such a simple task? Try the following:
Here is the Controller:

```
 app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.page = 1;
  $scope.last = 9999;
  $scope.next = function() {
    if (last < $scope.page) {
      $scope.page= $scope.page + 1;
    } else {
      $scope.page = 1;
    }
  };
  $scope.first = function() {
    $scope.page = 1;
  };
  $scope.prev = function() {
    $scope.page =$scope.page - 1;
  };
});
```

And your HTML:

```
<script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="../modules/myModule.js"></script>
    <script src="../Controllers/myController.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/MyScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
    <ul>
        <li><button ng-click="next()">Next</button></li>
        <li><button ng-click="first()">First</button></li>
        <li><button ng-click="prev()">Previous</button>/li>
    </ul>
    <img ng-src="'/images/image{{page}}.jpg'"></img> //Thank You MJH
</body>
</html>
```

All you are doing is changing a variable page which is reflected in the image source. Hope this works, and good luck.

EDIT: Added Click Functions

EDIT 2: I found why the image doesn't show, we didn't give the entire path (I forgot the /images/ part). That should fix it, if it doesn't change the path part in the img src. I also changed your a elements to buttons, for `ng-click` to work easily. The `ng-click` attribute takes a function, that function (for example `x()`) be defined in the scope with `$scope.x=function(){}`. Good Luck!

EDIT 3: Fixed Function and ng-src

Comment: I'm new to angular I don't understand how to use this to change the image. When I click Next, what will happen? How can I get the next image?

Comment: I'd like you to show just the next function. The logic doesn't matter. I'm a total beginner ~_~`.

Comment: I tried `scope.page = 1` and ` <img ng-src="'image' + page + '.jpg'" />` (it's actually a jpg, not an html, like in my question), but all I get is a small image missing logo. The image doesn't show. My images are not blocked.

Comment: See the updated answer, basically I had the wrong path, my bad.

Comment: I know. I changed to the right path but it still doesn't work. For some reason the single quotes inside the double qoutes are killing it. I changed to this:`"../images/image{{page}}.jpg"` and now it works. I'm interested if your way actually works for you. If not - you might want to update your answer. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. ^^

Comment: I used your code, but although the first image does appear, the buttons do not go to previous and next images. When I debug, I see the code go into the functions, but the I seem to get errors on the $scope.page+=1 and $Scope.page-=1..

Comment: Try the new functions please (it seems I can't do += like normal variables for some reason). And thanks for pointing out the problem with the ng-src string!

Comment: I tried `variable ++` and `variable = variable + 1`. Both didn't work.

Comment: Is the code firing? Try moving the ng-click to the li element